# Simplify multiple if statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm building a user module in PHP. It reads a text based user type and it assigns a numeric value to manage report view rights:

```
if ($usr_type == "Architect"){ $usr_rights = 0; }
if ($usr_type == "Director"){ $usr_rights  = 1; }
if ($usr_type == "Manager"){ $usr_rights  = 2; }
if ($usr_type == "Associate"){ $usr_rights  = 3; }
if ($usr_type == "Assistant"){ $usr_rights  = 4; }
if ($usr_type == "External"){ $usr_rights  = 5; }
```

Is there a simpler, more elegant way to do this?

Comment: FYI: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how the site works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `switch()` to do the if job.

```
switch($usr_type) {
    case "Architect":
        $usr_rights = 0;
    break;
    case "Director":
        $usr_rights  = 1;
    break;
    case "Manager":
        $usr_rights  = 2;
    break;
    case "Associate":
        $usr_rights  = 3;
    break;
    case "Assistant": 
        $usr_rights  = 4;
    break;
    case "External":
        $usr_rights  = 5;
    break;
}
```

Or use an array.

```
$valid_types = array(
                "Architect" => 0,
                "Director" => 1,
                "Manager" => 2,
                "Associate" => 3,
                "Assistant" => 4,
                "External" => 5
            );

if(isset($valid_types[$usr_type])) {
    $usr_rights = $valid_types[$usr_type];
}
```

Comment: an associative array is really the best option here

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 different solutions from your current one.

1. Make a switch statement like this:

```
switch($usr_type) {

    case "Architect":
        $usr_rights = 0;
    break;

    case "Director":
        $usr_rights = 1;
    break;

    //...

}
```

For more information about `switch()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

2. Or make a array and search in it like this:

```
$arr = array(0 => "Architect", 1 => "Director", 2 => "Manager", 3 => "Associate", 4 => "Assistant", 5 => "External");           

if(array_search($usr_type, $arr) !== false)
    $usr_rights = array_search($usr_type, $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
switch($usr_type) {

    case "Architect":
        $usr_rights = 0;
        break;

    case "Director":
        $usr_rights = 1;
        break;
    case "Manager":
        $usr_rights = 2;

    etc..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array functions `array_map`. If we consider "Architect", "Director", etc. are keys. Then we can use map structure to combine the keys and their values.

```
<?php
$usr_rights = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$usr_types = array("Architect", "Director", "Manager", "Associate", "Assistant","External");
$c = array_combine($usr_types,$usr_rights);
print_r($d);

// Test
echo $c["Architect"]; // output: 0
?>
```

See documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: @Casey: The better way to model such a data can use map structure. In the question, there are two elements: keys and its values. It exists a lot of use like: http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/some-handy-array-functions-in-php/ or http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_combine.asp.

Comment: Right, but you didn't have any of that code there when I comment, you just said use array-map. Doing it this way is also much more expensive than using a keyed array